# Issue in modifying the file updmap.cfg to install a new font on LaTeX

Tags: fonts, latex, miktex

I want to install the Garamond font on LaTeX and I followed the procedure given for *[urw-garamond](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond)*.
I have put the files where I had to but I stuck at the modification of the file **updmap.cfg**

Let me first say that by typing in the command line `updmap --verbose` I am told that three updmap.cfg files exist. One is in C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX..., one in C:\ProgramFiles\MiKTeX... and one in C:\Users\Peter\AppData...

I followed the procedure below:

0) `initexmf --update-fndb`

1) `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`

2) Write `Map ugm.map` on the last line (there is only one heading line, though)

3) `initexmf --mkmaps`

I did all that by using the command line in admin mode. I tried as well the commands above when adding `--admin`. I observed that without it the updmap file opened is in AppData, while with it the one in ProgramData is called.

Still I did not figure out how to modify the one in ProgramFiles, which is containing all the commands. The other updmap files in the other directories are just empty.

Answer (score 0):

I just found: all I had done is actually fine, but the files of *urw-garamond* have to be put in the AppData\Local folder and not in the Program Files one (which would be the most natural one).

To use the font I called then *mathdesign* by adding in the preamble `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}`